# Eclipse not displaying UTF-8 characters correctly in some cases (e.g. if following more than one upper case letter)

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8

Suppose the following test file encoded in `UTF-8`:

```
∈
a∈B
aa∈B
A∈B
AA∈B
```

My Eclipse (4.6.3) fails to display all `∈` characters in edit-view and console view.

edit-view looks like:

```
∈
a∈B
aa∈B
A∈B
AA?B
```

console view looks like:

```
∈
a∈B
aa?B
A∈B
AA?B
```

If printed using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Utf8Debug.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt"), "UTF-8")).lines().forEach(l -> System.out.println(l));`

The encoding of the file is set to UTF-8 at the properties.

What’s the problem and how to fix this?

One interesting observation is: During loading of the file the line `aa∈B` is displayed as `aa?B` first before automatically displayed correctly after approximately 1s.

PS: `?` indicates question mark in box

Comment: Maybe a filling a bug to Eclipse will solve the issue